# Why does Dictionary in C# Have a .Distinct() Extension?

Tags: c#, dictionary

As the title says, why does the Dictionary collection in C# contain a .Distinct() extension as if it's possible for a Dictionary to contain non-distinct keys? Is there legitimate reasoning behind this or am I reading too far into it?

Comment: @Bluetoft While all the dots following your statements would seem to indicate that this is rather obvious, it may be to you, but this actually has nothing to do with the values themselves, so *that* obvious it is not.

Comment: I somewhat disagree with the idea of it being "unneccesary". It's quite possible to create dupe keys in a `Dictionary` via mutable keys etc. Also being able to pass `IEqualityComparer<TSource>` may prove useful.

Comment: @TI if you are using mutiable keys you are breaking the contract with Dictionary's API and are going to get undefined behavior. However you are correct that `.Distinct(IEqualityComparer)` could be useful, but this question about the parameter-less version `.Distinct()`

Comment: @Bluetoft You're thinking of Dictionary.Values.Distinct() which returns an IEnumerable<T> of all distinct values in the dictionary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` which has a `Distinct` extension. The `Dictionary` class itself doesn't have an implementation of `Distinct`

Calling the `Distinct` is translated to a call to the static extension method:

```
Enueramble.Distinct(IEnumerable<T> source)
```

Which is unneccesary for `Dictionary` since keys are distinct (and hence key/value pairs are distinct) but technically there's nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 4):

The `Distinct` applies to the `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` interface from a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. While it doesn't make sense because a dictionary have unique keys, the extension will be present solely because `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`.

Answer (score 3):

The `Distinct()` extension method isn't *specifically* on dictinoary, but rather any `IEnumerable<T>`.

Since `Dictionary<T,U>` is an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T,U>>`, it gets this method, even if it's not necessarily appropriate for this class.

This is one disadvantage of extension methods - they "extend" any class which fits the first parameter, whether or not that specific class is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, and `Distinct` is an extension method of `IEnumerable<T>`, so it comes along for free, whether it's useful or not.

You are correct that it's technically impossible to have any duplicate objects in that particular sequence so long as `Distinct` is using the same `IEqualityComparer` as the `Dictionary`.  If you give the `Distinct` method a *custom* `IEqualityComparer` that uses a different definition of equality than what the `Dictionary` used then it is indeed possible for `Distinct` to find duplicates.

Comment: it is technically impossible to have any duplicate objects? Can you please explain this?

Comment: @EhsanUllah Dictionary can not have two items with the same key, therefor it is impossible to get two `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` items that have the same value for `.Key`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain i dont have VS here. Will try that out tomorrow. I didn't knew this. thanks for the info.

Comment: @EhsanUllah Why do you need VS?  The whole *point* of a dictionary is that it's a representation of the CS concept of a Map; it's fundamental to the data structure that there are no duplicate keys.  Just looking at the documentation for the type makes that clear.

Comment: @EhsanUllah If you need to store multiple values per key you must eiher use a [ILookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup.aspx) or have a `Dictionary<TKey,IEnumerable<TValue>>` type for the dictionary you create. (There is no class built in to .NET that provides `ILookup`, only the `.ToLookup` extension).

Answer (score 0):

I add another aspect that wasn´t mentioned before. As others mentioned the `Distinct` is actually an extension-method for `IEnumerable<T>`. However there´s also a second one that expects an `IEqualityComparer<T>`. Now you could write the following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var map = new Dictionary<int, int> { { 1, 1 }, { 2, 1 }, { 3, 1 } };
        var result = map.Distinct(new MyComparer());
    }

    class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<KeyValuePair<int, int>>
    {
        public bool Equals(KeyValuePair<int, int> x, KeyValuePair<int, int> y)
        {
            return x.Value == y.Value;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(KeyValuePair<int, int> obj)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

This programm will return the first `KeyValuePair` within the dictionary, as all  **values** within the map are equal. Of course there are better ways to achieve this.

Now you have `Dictionary<U, V>.Distinct(IEqualityComparer<U, V>)`, which *does* have some real use as shown above - and `Disitinct()`, which does not. Microsoft *could* have make some switch within `Distinct` to determine if we´re within any hashed-based collection. However that won´t add any benefit to that method. In fact it even returns the expected elements (all three ones in the example above).